# ABAP LIKE with select option

Tags: abap, opensql

I have the following abap program that looks as following:

```
TABLES lfa1.

DATA gt_lfa1 TYPE SORTED TABLE OF lfa1 WITH UNIQUE DEFAULT KEY.

SELECT-OPTIONS sl_lifnr FOR lfa1-lifnr.
SELECT-OPTIONS sl_name  FOR lfa1-name1.


START-OF-SELECTION.

  SELECT * FROM lfa1
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_lfa1
   WHERE lifnr IN sl_lifnr
   AND   name1 LIKE sl_name.
```

Searching for vendors that name starts with:

[image]

I've got no results, but it exists vendors with this pattern.

Comment: Why you dont use IN?

Comment: Yeah it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just put the asterisks into seltab and use `IN`. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to use `LIKE`. You can use `IN` instead.

I ran your code with `IN` in the SQL and I have results in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use a select option you have to use the statement IN not like:

s_matnr = *3578 *

```
select options s_matnr type mara-matnr.

select bismt

from mara 

into lv_bismt

where matnr in s_matnr
```

If you use s/4hana you can use even fuzzy

Answer (score -2):

You need to replace * with %, if you are using LIKE operand. https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/de-DE/abenwhere_logexp_like.htm

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURENCES OF '*' in sl_lifnr WITH '%'
REPLACE ALL OCCURENCES OF '*' in sl_name WITH '%'

SELECT * FROM lfa1
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE gt_lfa1
   WHERE lifnr LIKE sl_lifnr
   AND   name1 LIKE sl_name.
```